# J Install Error: Cannot Find "libedit.so"

Tags: linux, docker, j

I'm unsure if this is at root a Linux issue or a J specific issue.

#### Background

I'm trying to get j804 working inside a linux docker container.  I'm following the instructions here:

https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Installation/J804/Linux.

`j64-804` is in the container's home directory, and I'm logged in as root.  Here's the error I get:

```
$ ./j64-804/jconsole.sh
bin/jconsole: error while loading shared libraries: 
libedit.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm unsure how to debug from here.  What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

#### Other Possibly Relevant Details

```
root@b0ed60c2a313:~# find / -name libedit.so*
/opt/conda/pkgs/libedit-3.1.20170329-haf1bffa_1/lib/libedit.so.0
/opt/conda/pkgs/libedit-3.1.20170329-haf1bffa_1/lib/libedit.so.0.0.56
/opt/conda/pkgs/libedit-3.1.20170329-haf1bffa_1/lib/libedit.so
/opt/conda/lib/libedit.so.0
/opt/conda/lib/libedit.so.0.0.56
/opt/conda/lib/libedit.so
```

And those dirs are on my `PATH`.

- Linux system info returned from `uname -sr`: Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit
- Docker image I'm using: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/minimal-notebook

Comment: I don't  have an answer for you, but this is one that I would put up on the J forums. My guess would be that the general forum would be the best fit and generally people are very open to helping out. https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Forums#Forum_Mailing_Lists

Comment: can you do `file bin/jconsole` and `file /opt/conda/lib/libedit.so`, please? My guess is a mix between 32/64 bits libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libedit shared object is not being found by the jconsole executable - there are a few ways you can fix this.

First, shared object files are not searched for using `$PATH` to my knowledge: you need to change/create `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

For example, inside that Docker image, run:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/conda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

(You could also inject this environment variable when running the container; use the `-e` option for `docker run`.)

Then you have:

```
$ wget http://www.jsoftware.com/download/j804/install/j804_linux64.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf j804_linux64.tar.gz
$ ./j64-804/jconsole.sh
    3 + 1 4 1 5
4 7 4 8
```

Alternatively, you can modify the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/minimal-notebook/Dockerfile) to install libedit-dev during the build:

```
# Install all OS dependencies for fully functional notebook server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    emacs \
    git \
    inkscape \
    jed \
    libsm6 \
    libxext-dev \
    libxrender1 \
    libedit-dev \ # <----- here (or wherever you fancy)
    ...
```

This places the libedit shared objects in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` where the jconsole picks them up without the need for modifying environment variables.

If you have root access inside the image, you could also run `sudo apt-get install libedit-dev` there instead, or just link the shared objects into `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` using `ln -s` (although you'd have to do this every time you ran the image).